# Nginx "rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html""

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have pretty much a stock installation of LEMP on Ubuntu server that I was setting up just to host a few static files.

When setting up PHPNuke just for testing purposes, I noticed that I didn't have GD support installed. I had nginx set up with php5-fpm so ran "apt-get install php5-gd" to install the GD support libraries. After that though, nginx broke. Uninstalling php5-gd didn't fix it either. I get an error 500 in nginx and the error log comes up with the following:

```
2013/01/23 13:27:45 [debug] 16943#0: *16 http script var: "/index.html"
2013/01/23 13:27:45 [debug] 16943#0: *16 trying to use dir: "/index.html" "/etc/nginx/html/index.html"
2013/01/23 13:27:45 [debug] 16943#0: *16 trying to use file: "/index.html" "/etc/nginx/html/index.html"
2013/01/23 13:27:45 [error] 16943#0: *16 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 10.2.1.1, server: localhost, request: "GET$
2013/01/23 13:27:45 [debug] 16943#0: *16 http finalize request: 500, "/index.html?" a:1, c:12
2013/01/23 13:27:45 [debug] 16943#0: *16 http special response: 500, "/index.html?"
2013/01/23 13:27:45 [debug] 16943#0: *16 http set discard body
2013/01/23 13:27:45 [debug] 16943#0: *16 xslt filter header
2013/01/23 13:27:45 [debug] 16943#0: *16 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

No idea why this has happened, my config doesn't refer to /etc/nginx/html at all so have no idea why it would be trying to look for files in this directory. Here are my configs:

http://pastie.org/private/ynrprqgelt10nfzexvsqtq
http://pastie.org/private/2dnldzpjckfky0thdqlwa

Answer (score 1):

just got the same error, basically you need to specify the path to index.html. You probably have something like

```
try_files /index.html;
```

try

```
try_files $uri/index.html;
```

or

```
try_files /var/www/yourpath/index.html;
```

you need to change the directory structure to what you have.
After that - reload nginx. Make sure you reload the right process :) I had some issues with that after upgrading nginx on ubuntu.